# How to check the last available version of Chrome and Firefox using C# or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-mvc-4

One of the requirements of one of my clients is to show a message to a user that's using an older version of Firefox, Chrome, IE or Safari. For the last two it's easy (IE 9+ and Safari 5+). But for Firefox and Chrome, the requirement is that the site supports the current and the previous version of each browser.
To get the clients browser and version is quite simple, but I need to know what is the last version of each browser. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Why do you not care about being specific for IE and Safari, but care so much more that they're on chrome 28 vs chrome 27?

Comment: @KevinB : I think he has explicitly asked for Firefox and Chrome.  Anyway, I like this question but I don't have an answer.+1

Comment: I'm just trying to understand intent, because as far as i know, the only way this would be possible is if said browser had a property available that would state that information (very unlikely), or the browser vender offers an api that returns the latest version number.

Comment: @KevinB: point taken.

Comment: The reason why I don't care about IE or Safari, it's because those are "harcoded", eg, for IE only from 9+ and Safari is 5+. Only Chrome and Firefox, due to their update release frequency, have this awkward requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically, all you need is a place that keeps track of what the latest version of each browser (Ideally with a web service).

A quick Googling I was able to find: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/articles/latest-browser-versions.php

It's not a web service, but you could simply parse that HTML and get the latest version of each browser. Alternatively, you could keep track yourself and manually update this information in your database.

Comment: It's something like that or in [link](http://browsehappy.com) that I want to achieve. But I wonder if they manually update the versions or they get them from some webservice.

Comment: Website is no longer maintained in any case: Last Update: 9 January 2018

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever have to worry about IE when it comes to version enforcement. Exception being, of course, if you need a specific API that's just not available in previous versions of Chrome/Firefox, but in that case you'd look and enforce the API, not the browser version. Adding to that, if Chrome/Firefox don't have an API, chances are even the most bleeding edge version of IE won't either, so the point is moot. The fact is Firefox and Chrome, and in part Safari, are far ahead of IE when it comes to browser hosted capabilities that trying to enforce specific versions of the former would likely be a lot of wasted time and effort to yield nothing substantial.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538555/1221382). It has an export option that allows to export in JSON, XML...

Comment: Dead weblink here.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you don't check the browser version, instead try doing feature detection using, say, [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

What features of your client's site depends on specific versions of each browser? If you use Modernizr you could perform a check on a feature, say some video stuff, and if the current browser does not support that feature, then display a message to the user suggesting they upgrade their browser.

Detecting browser versions via Javascript is very flakey at best.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I'd say you need this kind of verification is because your webpage has features only available to latest browsers. Instead of relying on version numbers, I suggest learning Modernizr.js for your website.

http://modernizr.com/

It can detect particular html5/css3 features individually.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the only reason is client's request. He was told about the normal procedures to make sure a browser was compatible and nothing was going to break.
But since is the client who's paying and he wants this "feature", well, I might just give it to him.

Comment: True, no doubt about that @HugoParedes. However, as professionals, we also analyze the need vs. the want. Using Modernizr is a lot scalable than keeping a manifest of all browsers which are compatible and not. Too bad he's one of those "stubborn" clients. Good luck